# Is there a way to use woocommerce forms on other template?

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, registration, wc

I need to create a full registration page on my woocommerce site, and, I want to show the default WC forms, eg. form with address autoclomplete, state dropdown list etc...

Please, this is my last big achievement to complete this project.
Will apreciate anny suggestion :)

Comment: so you want the form with custom filed? there is lots of plugins for this.

Comment: No. I need populate the woocommerce data with the entries of this form that I will create on a separate page.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird request - try using some popular form plugins, such as Contact Form 7, Ninja Forms or Gravity Forms. they all have the req's you've asked for and can be easily installed and used in any WP site.

Comment: I guess I was not clear enough. I need populate the woocommerce data with the entries of this form that I will create on a separate page. Briefly, I need create a separate page with a full woocommerce registration fields.